# max_input_vars set even if commented in php.ini

Tags: php, post, ini

I have a strange problem in my PHP application. In my php.ini, I have commented out the `max_input_vars` directive, but when submitting 1-2k forms (I know it's kinda large), the last 200 post values are cut off. The strange thing is that I even restarted my Apache. My `phpinfo()` shows that limit is set to 1000. Is that the default value? How do I make `max_input_vars` unlimited?

Comment: Note that Suhosin affects this value. The Suhosin settings for get,post,cookies, and request .max_vars may cap the value lower than the setting in php.ini

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [**the manual**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php), there is indeed a default value of `1000` for `max_input_vars` *(look in the table at the beginning of the page)*.

If you want a value different than this default value of 1000, you will have to specify it -- and not comment the directive in your configuration.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to make `max_input_vars` *unlimited* ; you could set it to a *high enough* value, of course, but remember that this directive has been added recently as a security measure. Also, it doesn't make sense to set the `max_input_vars` to unlimited since then a malicious user could send a huge load of data and exhaust your memory.